# Flutter via "build method" permission granted but still multi image picker not opening... whereas it works in "debug and run --release method"... why?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-manifest, android-permissions, release

`enter code here`Androidmanifest.xml all permissions added. This permissions works fine when I run app in debug or release mode but when I use "build appbundle or build apk" the generated app does not open image picker(permissions not working as intended)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.viaviaapp.flutter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

I have also tried adding runtime permission via "permission_handler". App page where permission is actually required and used. Even if we do not add runtime permission the "the multi_image_picker" plugin already handles permissions but even though nothing works when I use "build apk" and use it.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkPermissions();
  }

checkPermissions() async {
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isUndetermined) {
      Permission.storage.request();
      Permission.camera.request();
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isDenied) {
      showDialog(
          context: (context),
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                content: Text(
                  'viaviaapp requires permissions to storage and camera so that you can post images',
                  style: TextStyle(height: 1.3),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      } else {
                        Permission.storage.request();
                        Permission.camera.request();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Grant Now"),
                  )
                ],
              ));
    } else if (await Permission.storage.request().isPermanentlyDenied) {
      showDialog(
          context: (context),
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                shape: ContinuousRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                content: Text(
                  'You have to grant required permission from the application settings.',
                  style: TextStyle(height: 1.3),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      } else {
                          openAppSettings();
                      }
                    },
                    child: Text("Open Settings"),
                  )
                ],
              ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you found a fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me

```
flutter build apk --no-shrink
```